# Wordpress conflict with multiple load more posts functions on click

Tags: wp-query, jquery, ajax

I'm developing a single page application (SAP) based theme, where I've **Portfolio** CPT to show portfolio items in loop other than blog posts.

I've built 2 separate posts load more function which triggers on click. SO the blog posts are working fine, but on click on load more button on **Portfolio** section it appends posts for Blog instead of Portfolio.

Following I've Code Functions for Blog.

**blog-functions.php**

```
// Enqueing Scripts for loading blogs posts via Ajax
wp_enqueue_script('ajax_blog_scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/blog-scripts.js', array(), false, true );
wp_localize_script('ajax_blog_scripts', 'ajaxurl', admin_url('admin-ajax.php') );

// Initiating Ajax Load More Posts Function
function loadmore_blog_posts() {

    $count = $_POST["count"];
    $cpt = 1;
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type'   => 'post', // change the post type if you use a custom post type
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    );

    $blog_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( $blog_posts->have_posts() ) {
        while( $blog_posts->have_posts() ) {
            $blog_posts->the_post();

            if( $cpt > $count && $cpt < $count+3 ) {

                <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('post-item'); ?>>
                    Post Content...
                </article>

            <?php }
            $cpt++;
        }
    }

    die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_load_more_posts', 'loadmore_blog_posts' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load_more_posts', 'loadmore_blog_posts' );
```

**blog-scripts.js**

```
// Load Next Posts via AJAX Request
$('#blog-section .load-more-btn').click(function() {

    // Adding Loading Posts spinner on click
    var $btn = $(this).button('loading');

    // Sending Ajax Request for getting more Posts
    $.post(ajaxurl, {

        'action': 'load_more_posts',
        'count': $('article.post-item').length

    }, function(response) {

        $('#blog-section .blog-posts').append(response);

        $btn.button('reset');

    });

});
```

**Loop Markup**

```
<div class="blog-posts">

    <?php
    $args = array( 'order' => $blog_post_order, 'posts_per_page' => $blog_post_count );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 

    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    ?>

    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('post-item col-sm-6'); ?>>
        Post Content...
    </article>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; else :  ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, there is no post added so far. Please go to Dashboard and add one.', 'theme-slug' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>

</div>
```

Following I've Code Functions for Portfolio.

**portfolio-scripts.php**

```
// Enqueing Scripts for loading portfolio posts via Ajax
wp_enqueue_script('ajax_portfolio_scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/portfolio-scripts.js', array(), false, true );
wp_localize_script('ajax_portfolio_scripts', 'ajaxurl', admin_url('admin-ajax.php') );


// Initiating Ajax Load More Posts Function
function loadmore_portfolio_posts() {

    $count = $_POST["count"];
    $cpt = 1;
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type'   => 'portfolio', // change the post type if you use a custom post type
        'post_status' => 'publish',
    );

    $portfolio_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

    if( $portfolio_posts->have_posts() ) {
        while( $portfolio_posts->have_posts() ) {
            $portfolio_posts->the_post();

            if( $cpt > $count && $cpt < $count+5 ) { ?>

                <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('col-xl-2 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 portfolio-item'); ?>>
                    Loop Content
                </div>

            <?php }

            $cpt++;
        }
    }

    die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_load_more_posts', 'loadmore_portfolio_posts' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load_more_posts', 'loadmore_portfolio_posts' );
```

**portfolio-scripts.js**

```
// Load Next Posts via AJAX Request
$('#portfolio-section .load-more-btn').click(function() {

    // Adding Loading Posts spinner on click
    var $btn = $(this).button('loading');

    // Sending Ajax Request for getting more Posts
    $.post(ajaxurl, {

        'action': 'load_more_posts',
        'count': $('div.portfolio-item').length

    }, function(response) {

        $('#portfolio-section .portfolio-items').append(response);

        $btn.button('reset');

    });

});
```

**Loop Markup**

```
<div class="portfolio-items">
    <?php
    $args = array( 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'order' => $portfolio_post_order, 'posts_per_page' => $portfolio_post_count );
    $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); 

    if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>

    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('col-xl-2 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 portfolio-item'); ?>>
        Loop Content
    </div>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; else :  ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Sorry, there is no post added so far. Please go to Dashboard and add one.', 'theme-slug' ); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: please do the minimum of debugging before to ask a question. that means looking at every variable to see if the contains the expected values and writing these values in the question. look also this page : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php

Comment: I already have tried to mess with it but no luck. Thats why I've posted my query here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to you guyz after your help & little bit of searching i finally manage to get this done. As far as i realize, the issue was with **wp_localize_script**. On both **blog-functions.php** & **portfolio-functions.php**.

The issue was with the **$object_name**, so I've make it unique prior to **ajaxurl**. Below is my updated code.

**blog-functions.php**

```
wp_localize_script('ajax_blog_scripts', 'postAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
```

**portfolio-functions.php**

```
wp_localize_script('ajax_portfolio_scripts', 'portfolioAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
```

jQuery Variable for each Ajax $Object_Name

**blog-scripts.js** - `postAjax.ajaxurl`

**portfolio-scripts.js** - `portfolioAjax.ajaxurl`

Answer (score 0):

check your portfolio-scripts.js and blog-scripts.js both action contain same action.

> 'action': 'load_more_posts',

So for your portfolio-scripts.js action Should be

> 'action': 'loadmore_portfolio_posts',

instead of

> 'action': 'load_more_posts',

You declare the function in portfolio-scripts.php but not call in the ajax. I guess change the action solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the message Faysal Mahamud.
After updating action for Portfolio, its still not fixed yet. Now I'm getting '0' instead of Blog posts.

Comment: where you change.. both actions!!! you just change portfolio-scripts.js then it must be work. then do some debugging. You said your first script worked fine. Just problem was in the portfolio, so do change 'action': 'loadmore_portfolio_posts', and it should work. If not let me know i will try to figure out.

Comment: Thanks for the message. And yes I only change it to portfolio-scripts.js as you suggested before, but it wasn't working. Anyhow I'm still trying to figure out the way to solve this. I'll update my response here if i manage to  resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

With AJAX, you need to `echo` your return values, right before the call to `die()`.  So instead of

```
  if( $cpt > $count && $cpt < $count+3 ) {

            <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class('post-item'); ?>>
                Post Content...
            </article>

        <?php }
```

Try storing your output in a variable, like this:

```
$content = '';
if( $cpt > $count && $cpt < $count+3 ) {
   $content .= "<article id=post-" . the_ID(); . post_class('post-item'); . "Post Content... </article>";
}
```

Then at the end of the function, send it back to the AJAX calling function:

```
echo $content;
wp_die();
```